# How to recover damaged Excel files

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-recovery

I have a few Excel files which are not working since a sudden attack by some unknown virus. It then encrypted all my values in the datasheets. I have no backup for those Excel files. I need to recover my Excel files back to the previous state.

When I uploaded the corrupted file to Google Drive and then tried to open it with *Open with* -> *Google Sheets*, it showed an error saying "Unable to convert document".

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: You restore them from a back up

Comment: There is no back up for those excel files

Comment: Sigh... I bet you'll start taking back ups now though :(  I assume that the nonsense isn't a font (not being patronizing but best to ask :) ). You could try to open the excel file with winrar or zip (an excel file/word file are compressed folders) and have a look to see if the original data is there, but it would appear as if the file is corrupted, there is nothing you yourself can do. I assume you've looked for 3rd party tools?

Comment: Pretty difficult to decrypt something if you don't even know what encrypted it. I'm assuming this isn't ransomware, or you'd have said so. If it **is** ransomware, pay the ransom.

Comment: Tetsujin,its not a ransomware.some anonymous individual sent an email to my office email account with a zipped file and once the zipped file was opened,the virus destroyed the excel files with all the encrypted language as per the screenshot provided.

Comment: Dave,i tried recovering the files with Libreoffice,ExcelFIX but to no avail.tried the winrar/zip fix also.it did not work

Comment: **Envoyé de mon Galaxy S6 edge+ Orange** -- 

this was the name of the virus.i looked it up on the internet and it seems other people had this issue also.

[Photos pretending to come from your own email address](https://myonlinesecurity.co.uk/photos-pretending-to-come-from-your-own-email-address-supposed-to-be-malware-but-empty-zips/)

Comment: "These malicious attachments normally have a password stealing component, with the aim of stealing your bank, PayPal or other financial details along with your email or FTP ( web space) log in credentials. Many of them are also designed to specifically steal your Facebook and other social network log in details. A very high proportion are Ransomware versions that encrypt your files and demand money ( about £350/$400) to recover the files."

Comment: Looks like ransomware that encrypted the files and forgot to ask for the money ...

Comment: How did it encrypt the data in the sheet? Or did it encrypt the sheet with a password that [you can decrypt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project)?

Comment: I cannot decrypt the file back to its previous state.i have read something about the Cisco routers getting the same virus.it doesn't ask for a password to decrypt.i have the affected file with me if anyone wants to have a look.

Comment: ransomware must have forgotten to ask for the money.

Comment: @Tetsujin paying the ransom is a bad thing though. Recovering from properly versioned backups should be the thing to do. We can't encourage this sorta thing ;)